# python read each line in a text file and put anything between START and END in a new file

Tags: python

I have a text file i've imported which has no blank lines and looks like this... Each of these things are on a separate line.

```
--START--some data
one line
two line
three line
--END--
four
five
--START-- some data
six 
seven
eight
--END--
nine 
ten
eleven
--START-- some data
```

**What I want**

I have already written code to open the file and loop through each line and find the ones which contain start.

```
import codecs
file = codecs.open('data.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()
for line in file:

    if '--START--' in line:
    #found the start line (keep all lines until you find END)
```

What I don't know how to do is create the logic in python where each line that either begins with START or is after that (until but not including the END line) goes into a new text file.

So I would end up with NewFile.txt which contained only:

```
--START--some data
one line
two line
three line
--START-- some data
six 
seven
eight
--START-- some data
```

Answer (score 1):

you mean something like

```
file_contents = open('data.txt',"rb").read()
with open("newfile.txt","wb") as f:
      f.write("--START--".join(p.split("--END--")[0] for p in file_contents.split("--START--")))
```

Comment: Joran Thanks I think this worked except it didn't export in the same unicode format with separate lines. Is there a way to modify my open new file command to create a unicode txt file with the lines in the original file preserved? f = open("html.txt", "w")
print >> f, result

Comment: sure there you go(see edit) ... (just open it with the normal open ...  what you are working with(your search terms) is all ascii so it really doesnt matter that its utf8 encoded)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

> ```
> import codecs
> file = codecs.open('data.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()
> startblock = 0
> for line in file:
>     if '--END--' in line:
>         startblock = 0
>     elif '--START--' in line or startblock:
>         # Write to file
>         startblock = 1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
from  itertools import takewhile
with open("in.txt") as f:
    final = []
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("--START--"):
            final += [line] + list(takewhile(lambda x: not x.startswith("--END--"),f))
print(final)
['--START--some data\n', 'one line\n', 'two line\n', 'three line\n', '--START-- some data\n', 'six \n', 'seven\n', 'eight\n', '--START-- some data']
```

To write the new data:

```
from  itertools import takewhile
with open("in.txt") as f,open("out.txt","w") as f1:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("--START--"):
            f1.write(line + "".join(list(takewhile(lambda x: not x.startswith("--END--"),f))))
```